# Pass Parameters by Reference into AJAX JSON callback

Tags: c#, ajax, json

Not quite sure how I pass a parameter by ref to a AJAX JSON callback C#.NET, e.g. if I have a web method like this:

```
[WebMethod] 
public static string MyMethod(Int32 x, Int32 y, ref Int32 z) 
{ 
  z =  x + y;
  return "Finished!";
}
```

How do I set up the call below to get the CHANGED value of z without returning it?

```
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ x:1, y:1, z:0}); 
    $.ajax({ 
         type: "POST", 
         url: "myPage.aspx/MyMethod", 
         data: jsonText, 
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
         dataType: "json", 
         success: function () { alert("Success"); }, 
         failure: function () { alert("Failure"); } 
    });
```

Comment: Why can't you just return z? I don't think there is a way to get a reference to z since serializer is involved.

Comment: what the hell are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is just an dumb example to ask whether I can pass by ref.  In reality, I'm returning a result set of products from a stored proc. And I want to return an output parameter value from the stored proc in addition to the result set.  So I guess what you're telling me is that the only thing you can output out the method is the return value.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the value of Z without returning it.  When posting to a WebMethod , you send a copy of your arguments.  Similarly, when the web-method returns data, it returns a copy.  Your WebMethod does not use the same memory as whatever entity is posting to it (most likely your web-browser).  How would you expect a remote WebMethod to change the value, in memory, in your browser?

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379648/net-webservices-and-out-ref-webmethod-arguments