# C# Web Service with a reference parameter

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, pass-by-reference

I must create a C# web service. I have a question. Is possible to use a `ref` parameter?
For example, I have this method

```
//my web service will fill the parameter by reference
int myWSMethod(int parameterA, ref string parameterB);
```

Is this possible with a web service?

Comment: Why don't you pass the information is as a regular parameter can you explain the need for why you think you would need a ref Param take a look at this `SO` posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379648/net-webservices-and-out-ref-webmethod-arguments

Comment: When you exchange a variable over a web service, it becomes serialized. What do you expect `ref` to do? Please explain the real issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: @ DJ KRAZE I would like to use this type of parameter because I want to have a method that returns an error code (return int) but also a report (ref parameter) of web service esecution

Comment: @GgSalent a better approach would be to return the string value and _throw a custom exception_ on error rather than using a `ref` parameter

Comment: @DStanley No, see google's, twitter's etc. APIs. all return and object containing a `status` and the actual data. So `EkoostikMartin`'s solution is fine.

Answer (score 6):

If your problem is just trying to figure out how to return multiple values from a web service, just return a complex type instead.

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class myWSMethodResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Report { get; set; }
}

public myWSMethodResponse myWSMethod(int parameterA)
{
  //code here
}
```

Comment: Whilst not what the OP was asking, this definitely seems like the most sensible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do it, but based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070.aspx), you can do that.

> **`Out` and `Ref` Parameters**.
>
> In most cases, you can use in parameters (`ByVal` in Visual Basic) and `out` and `ref`
>       parameters (`ByRef` in Visual Basic). Because both `out` and `ref` parameters indicate 
>       that data is returned from an operation, an operation signature such as the following 
>       specifies that a request/reply operation is required even though the operation signature returns `void`.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> [ServiceContractAttribute]
> public interface IMyContract
> {
>   [OperationContractAttribute]
>   public void PopulateData(ref CustomDataType data);
> }
> ```